# Boudary conditions for magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, boundary-conditions

I am studying electromagnetism, in particular boundary conditions for magnetic field, and I have a question.

It is clear to me the demonstration of the normal component of the magnetic field:

$ \int (\vec{B} \cdot \hat{n}) d \Sigma = \int (\nabla \cdot \vec{B} ) dV = 0$
$ \rightarrow B_{1n} = B_{2n} $

given a surface like this one:

[image]

Suppose now we are in isotropic mediums where it is true that: $ \vec{B} = \mu \vec{H}$

Can we do the same previous argument ?

$ \int (\vec{H} \cdot \hat{n}) d \Sigma = \int (\nabla \cdot \vec{H} ) dV = 0$
$ \rightarrow H_{1n} = H_{2n} \rightarrow  \frac{B_{1n}}{\mu_2} = \frac{B_{2n}}{\mu_1}$

where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mu$ depends on the coordinate, $\nabla\cdot\vec{H}$ is not equal to 0, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\nabla\cdot\vec{H}&=\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\mu(x,y,z)}\vec{B}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{\mu(x,y,z)}\nabla\cdot\vec{B}+\nabla\left(\frac{1}{\mu(x,y,z)}\right)\cdot\vec{B} \\
&=\nabla\left(\frac{1}{\mu(x,y,z)}\right)\cdot\vec{B} \\
&\neq 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
For a simple example, let us assume that the case is only z-dependent and uniform in the x and y directions,
In this case $B_z$ is constant and no dependence on z.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial H_z}{\partial z} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{1}{\mu(z)}B_z\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{1}{\mu(z)}\right)B_z \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{1}{\mu_2}1(z)+\frac{1}{\mu_1}1(-z)\right)B_z \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{\mu_2}\delta(z)-\frac{1}{\mu_1}\delta(z)\right)B_z \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\mu_2}-\frac{1}{\mu_1}\right)\delta(z)B_z \neq 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $1(z)$ is the Heaviside step function and $\delta(z)$ is the Dirac delta function.

Answer (score 2):

First off, if your homogeneous, isotropic medium fills out all of space, then there is no boundary condition to speak of.

However, if it fills a strict subset, then you will not have:
$$
\nabla \cdot H = 0
$$
anymore. Indeed, you reasoning only works within the bulk of the media. However, at the boundary (which is what you are interested in), it would pick up the sharp variation in $\mu$ giving a Dirac delta term. This is why you must consider $B$ for the normal discontinuity to be $0$.

Hope this helps.